# Which online text-to-speech engine is more accurate?

Tags: single-words, pronunciation

I did some research and it appears like there are few or no online resources for Italian pronunciation (I hope that I am wrong).

Which text-to-speech engine is more accurate for Italian words among 
http://translate.google.com and http://translate.yandex.com?

Comment: What do you mean by “IPA web sites”? The International Phonetic Association itself has a great [website](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/) with lots of information about IPA.

Comment: As for the rest, planning to learn how to pronounce a language from a speech synthesiser is like learning interpersonal skills from Siri.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to agree with @DaG here. I don't think that either is meaningfully "superior", in the sense that to a learner both of them are probably very damaging. Try to get the correct pronunciation from websites that record native speakers (like [Forvo](https://forvo.com/)) or from audiobooks and movies and not from speech synthesizers.